# Why is javafx.mail.jar Java library not found in my IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Does anybody knows a link or site that I could find this Java library?

The problem is there is a Java program that my employer needs me to fix a bug but the problem is that the person that was the author of the program is not anymore working with him so he needs me to fix it but the IDE is looking for a library that is **javafx.mail.jar** and so far as I was searching the web there were no answers of this kind of file type.

Can someone knows about this type? Thank you in advance

***FYI: I'm new in Java so please be nice :)***

Comment: Are you sure, that is it " javafx.mail.jar" ? Can you post a summary of the content (classnames) of the JAR content? So we might be able to guess, what library is needed here or if it is something hand-crafted.

Comment: Actually after going deep through the codes its actually a javax.mail file it was just renamed to javafx.mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure<sup>1</sup> you should be looking for the JAR file for `javax.mail`, not `javafx.mail`.

You can get the JAR file from [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail), from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) or from [GitHub](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/), depending on what version you need.

---

<sup>1 - The Oracle `javafx` product has nothing to do with email.  Either you have misread something, or the code you are trying to fix is currently referring to something that doesn't exist ... and you need to fix *that*.  The `javafx` package tree is reserved for the use of the `javafx` product line itself.  3rd party libraries should not define packages in that tree.</sup>

Comment: Yes! I get your point but the script was really looking for a javafx.mail, but apparently I just realized last night that maybe the previews person that was in charge of this script renamed javax.mail to javafx.mail.

So far it runs but need to double check if it has any bugs, Thanks by the way